# Is author.php a core file?

Tags: author, profiles, author-template

I want to change the author.php with more information. Can i edit author.php without it remove my code, after a Wordpress update? Or is there some hook for this.

Comment: It isn't a core file, it is a theme template file, take a look [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about `author.php` in your theme directory, usually at `wp-content/themes/<YOURTHEMENAME>` this isn't a core file but part of your theme.

Themes don't get changed when WordPress is updated, so concerning WordPress updates themes are safe.

**But** if your theme isn't custom made by you (which I assume here) this file would be changed if you update your theme. So to be safe you should create a child theme as child themes make it possible to update the parent theme while keeping your child theme changes. Details about [how to create a child theme can be found at the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `author.php` file in your theme folder to make your custom author template. This is the tempalte hierachy for author view:

1. author-{nicename}.php - If the author's nice name were rami, WordPress would look for author-rami.php.
2. author-{id}.php - If the author's ID were 6, WordPress would look for author-6.php.
3. author.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php